# FInding index of values

Tags: list, indexing, list-comprehension, indices

I have a list of lists, [[-1,-1,1,1,1],[-1,-1,1,1,1]] is there some way to have the program return the indices that equal -1? Therefore when I put that list into the comprehension, it would return that the value = -1 at the indices [0][0], [0][1], [1][0], [1][1].

Answer (score 0):

Track the indices with both indices of a nested for-loop: i and j

Track the occurance of the -1 with an if conditional, and return i and j.

Spoiler alert in Ruby, not sure your language:

```
twoDeeArr = [[-1,-1,1,1,1],[-1,-1,1,1,1]]

i = 0
while i < twoDeeArr.length do
    j = 0
    while j < twoDeeArr[i].length do
        if twoDeeArr[i][j] == -1
            puts "Danger Will Robinson: at #{i},#{j}"
        end
        j+= 1
    end
    i+= 1
end

### RETURNS
Danger Will Robinson: at 0,0
Danger Will Robinson: at 0,1
Danger Will Robinson: at 1,0
Danger Will Robinson: at 1,1
```

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, im using python, could you tell me in that language? Thanks

Comment: I think it would be a good exercise to convert. Just look for "loop through array Python" and map the syntax up.